# Excel 2013 - Formula to return text if an error is found

Tags: excel

I have Column A that contains an error (#N/A) and many other different determined values.

In Column B, I want a formula to provide a simple "Yes" or "No" depending upon if the contents in Column A is an error or not, so I can use the Yes/No response in a pivot table.

Syntax would be using IFERROR:

```
     If cell A1 = #N/A, then return "No", else return "Yes".
```

I have been trying different forums to find the answer - Could someone help.
It must follow the rules above, not using MATCH to reference a control cell containing "Yes" or "No".

Thanks

Comment: `=IF(ISNA(A1), "No", "Yes")`

Comment: Perfect, thanks Tim!

Answer (score 1):

See the below ways we can achieve the errors

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1),"Yes","No")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(A1,"Yes")
```

or

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(ERROR.TYPE(A1)),"Yes","No")
```